# Terminate the session on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a requirement that is :--

On click of ‘Logout’ link, popup message “This will terminate the session and close the browser. Do you want to continue?” with Yes and No buttons. On click of ‘Yes’, session should be terminated in IIS server and current tab of browser closed.

To implement this I have writen below piece of code but I dont know how to terminate the session on IIS

```
    <script language="vbscript">
            Function OnClickLogout() 
                dim Answer, msg
                Msg = "This will terminate the session and close the browser. Do you want to continue?"
                Answer = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Error")
                if Answer = vbYes then
                    window.close
                else
                    'Retrun to the previous page
                end if
            End Function
        </script>
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to do this in vbscript. My website is in ASP but its a legacy application so I have to do the code!!!

Comment: I think you would want to use a post to the server.  and run your script to stop the submit if they choose no.  If they choose yes you would use Session.Abandon() on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply use JavaScript? We us it all the time at work in our ASP Classic projects. Something like that to start off:

```
    function DeleteProductGroup(){
        var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product group?");
        if (r==true){//here goes the code if user presses YES
        }
        else{//here goes the code if user presses NO
        }
    }
```